# Can't open file in PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to open a file with [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP) for write access:

```
$myFile = "all.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
```

My browser is spitting back:

> can't open file

I've tried to chmod -R 777 the folder where this PHP file is as well as where $myFile (a text file) sits. What else could be the problem?

It ends up being that there are permission errors when I turn error reporting on. When I do `ls -la all.txt`, I get `-rwx------  1 Myname  staff  0 Nov  8 15:11 all.txt`

Comment: are both files in the same directory?

Comment: You should be getting a warning from `fopen`

Comment: yes they are in the same directory

Comment: how do I get that error message?

Comment: add `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors','1');` to the top of the script

Comment: okay the error is : failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/blah/blah/~blah/blah/Upload.php on line 53 can't open file

Comment: at a shell run `ls -l all.txt` let us know the result

Comment: -rwx------  1 Myname  staff  0 Nov  8 15:11 all.txt

Comment: as you can see permissions are 700 no 777

Comment: chmod again, (run as root), as its read owner only, and the webserver user is unlikely to be the owner

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the script is started from other directory, please try open file from the full [URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier).

Example:

```
$myFile = '/path/to/myFile.txt';
if (!file_exists($myFile)) {
  print 'File not found';
}
else if(!$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w')) {
  print 'Can\'t open file';
}
else {
  print 'Success open file';
}
```

Comment: This returned "Can't open file"

Comment: Please check errors!
`ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
`

Comment: yes, it is a permissions error once I add those.

Comment: Google chmod if its a permission error