# PHP file handling program on laravel 4.2

Tags: php, laravel-4, file-handling

I want to open a php file with a file handling code on it using laravel 4.2

Here is the php code that I have

```
<html> 
  <head> 
      <title>Gyoza</title>
      <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "{{URL::asset('styleCenter.css') }}">     
  </head> 
  <body>  

    <img src="gyoza.jpg" width =250px height =250px>

    <?php 
        $filename = "gyoza.txt"; 

        $file = fopen( $filename, "r" ); 
        if( $file == false ) 
        { 
            echo ( "Error in opening file" ); 
            exit(); 
        } 

        $filesize = filesize( $filename ); 
        $filetext = fread( $file, $filesize ); 

        fclose( $file );  

        echo ( "<pre>$filetext</pre>" ); 

    ?>  
  </body> 
</html>
```

When I run this program it shows this error
fopen(gyoza.txt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Comment: Formatted his HTML to be easier to read and fixed grammar mistakes.

Comment: what? can you please explain your answer?

Answer (score 1):

Two comments:

1. It is not needed to use `exit();` cause this will stop rendering the rest html inside the view.
2. `error fopen(gyoza.txt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory` means that the file could not be found in the path where the view reside. Just as example, take a note about path using laravel's native functions:

   ```
   // file at your-app/app/storage/gyonza.txt
   fopen(base_path('app/storage/gyoza.txt');

   // file at your-app/public/gyonza.txt
   fopen(public_path('gyoza.txt');
   ```

#### Edit: About paths

When you make a laravel installation, by default the structure of its directories looks like:

```
laravel-app/
    /app
    /app/storage
    /app/storage/logs/laravel.log
    /app/views
    /app/views/home.blade.php
    /test.txt
    /public/robots.txt
```

So, if you want to access some contained in this structure, you have some alternatives/shortcuts to access a particular file. For example:

**public_path()** is the shortcut to `/laravel-app/public` path:

```
public_path('robots.txt')
```

**base_path()** is the shortcut to `/laravel-app/` path:

```
base_path('test.txt')
```

**app_path()** is the shortcut to `/laravel-app/app` path:

```
app_path('storage/logs/laravel.log')
```

Comment: could also be permission issue.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13297145/cant-open-file-in-php

Comment: When is due to permission issue the error is different: `Warning: fopen(gyoza.txt): failed to open stream: Permission denied`.. I guess

Comment: May I ask what is the difference between public_path and base_path?