# Facing an issue in transferring WordPress website

Tags: php, wordpress

When I transfer my wordpress website from demo link to original I am facing some issues. The following are the warnings and errors that I get
please help.

```
Warning: fopen(/home/interactive/public_html/coolblue-web/wp-content/plugins/foogallery/foogallery.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/coolblueco/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 4786

Warning: fread() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/coolblueco/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 4789

Warning: fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/coolblueco/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 4792

Warning: fopen(/home/interactive/public_html/coolblue-web/wp-content/plugins/foobox-image-lightbox/foobox-free.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/coolblueco/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 4786

Warning: fread() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/coolblueco/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 4789

Warning: fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/coolblueco/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 4792

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/coolblueco/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php:4786) in /home/coolblueco/public_html/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1210
```

Refer this: [coolblue.co.tz](http://coolblue.co.tz/)

Comment: Have you checked what folder php is in when it tries to open `/home/...`?  You are using relative paths, and the start from wherever the script starts. So probably php can't find the folder you are pointing from.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't open file in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13297145/cant-open-file-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

Delete the Foo Gallery plugin and reinstall it. It's broken or missing

Comment: I cant login to dashboard

Comment: Do you have FTP access to the site?

Comment: Yes. I have the FTP access

Comment: Navigate to your `/wp-content/plugins/` directory and delete the foogallery directory, or rename it to `foogallery-x` to forcefully disable it

Comment: OK. What else I have to do

Comment: Download the plugin manually: https://wordpress.org/plugins/foogallery/

Unzip it and upload it via ftp to the same directory, and then the fopen errors should go away

Comment: Error is gone. But still no result

Comment: What is the status now? @SarathNairC